# How to populate Table with JSON object which is return Spring MVC+Hibernate restful web services?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I want to populate my JQuery table with JSON object which is return by Spring MVC. 
My JSON Data formate is

```
{
availDate: 1421508979000
custName: "Navin"
custMobile: "8765432468"
custEmail: "abc@gmail.com"
custAddress: "BAngalore"
}
```

My service url for fetching Data is 
**http://localhost:8080/HomeServiceProvider/booking/getAllBookingDetails**
But My code is not working, please check it..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>     
            <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>       
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
             <script>
              $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#example').dataTable( {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost:8080/HomeServiceProvider/booking/getAllBookingDetails" // for you it will be - /getWidgetsByType
              } );
            } );
            </script>       
        </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>availDate</th>
                    <th>custName</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>custMobile</th>
                    <th>custAddress</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the column names and their respective data (JSON key values) in your data table:

```
"columns" : [ {
    "mData" : "availDate",
    "bSortable" : true
}, {
    "mData" : "custName",
    "bSortable" : true
}, {
    "mData" : "custMobile",
    "bSortable" : true
}, {
    "mData" : "custEmail",
    "bSortable" : true
}, {
    "mData" : "custAddress",
    "bVisible" : false
}]
```

Check for the [data table API](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) for column usage.